# Confused with Dialogflow and Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I've recently started learning and developing a chat bot with Dialog flow. The chat bot will be used as mobile app and web integration as well.

While using dialogflow fulfillment, I used to edit inline fulfillment editor which already had some samples. Card & Suggestion were imported from dialogflow-fulfillment library and used. Up to that point all is fine.

But, when i tried to use Carousel, List etc from actions by importing them from actions-on-google  library, it is working with Android Google Assistant, but response for web is saying, "cannot display response in Dialogflow simulator. Please test on the Google Assistant simulator...."

What actually I expect to do is, using modules/components of actions on google along with components of dialogflow fulfillment, without any issues for mobile apps and web.

Or else, looking for best way to to this.

Comment: Test it with ActionsOnGoogle simulator, you will find it under `test` menu in actions console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dialogflow and Actions on Google are two separate things, although they work together. Having a better understanding of each may help you understand when to use each.

Actions on Google is a way for developers to build voice experiences on top of the Google Assistant across surfaces. As a platform it takes in user queries through voice primarily, and returns sensible responses.

It's hard to do natural language processing. Getting a user's query may not be sufficient to understand what they mean. So Dialogflow serves as a platform that acts as an intermediary, taking in a raw query and making sense of it.

Dialogflow is a general NLP platform, and supports a variety of platforms including Actions on Google, Slack, Twitter, and more.

As each platform has different APIs, Dialogflow has tried to create a common set of features in their `dialogflow-fulfillment` library. Cards will work across platforms.

However, Actions on Google supports a wider range of response types such as carousels. When using a carousel, you should use the `actions-on-google` library for your fulfillment as it is designed to support this wider range of response types. Additionally, features like permissions and account linking are also exclusive to Actions on Google, and should be written in that way.

Comment: Got a clear understanding of Dialogflow vs Actions on Google. I want to customize responses in dialogflow inline editor and use them in mobile app and web chat bot. How can i do it? 
I read about payload, but couldn't get how can I customize it in inline editor.

Comment: You want different responses based on Actions on Google versus web chatbot?

Comment: @NitheesramRajes, I would suggest to try out the Google Codelabs sample app creation tutorial here, https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/actions-1/#0  for developing Dialogflow fullfilment for AOG.

Comment: @NickFelker When I tried to use components from Actions Library, i could not get the response for Web Bot, instead I receive a message saying 'response only for Action Simulator...' 
As I understood dialogflow fulfillment has 4 components in its own. It doesn't have components such as Carousel, List view etc. 


Let's say, I want a carousel for my all chat bots (G Assistant, FB, Twitter, Own web bot and mobile app). How can I do it?

Comment: There's no way to do it as platforms like Twitter or FB just do not support a carousel type.

Comment: Are `Actions on Google` available in Slack? I tried to talk to my bot and these don't show up there.

Comment: Actions on Google is for the Google Assistant, not anywhere else.